# How can I make a request including "à" character in its URL in Python?

Tags: python, url, encoding, python-requests

I use the requests module in Python to fetch a result of a web page. However, I found that if the URL includes a character `à` in its URL, it issues the UnicodeDecodeError:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 27: invalid continuation byte

Strangely, this only happens if I also add a space in the URL. So for example, the following does not issue an error.

```
requests.get("http://myurl.com/àieou")
```

However, the following does:

```
requests.get("http://myurl.com/àienah aie")
```

Why does it happen and how can I make the request correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the lib urllib to auto-encode characters.

```
import urllib
requests.get("http://myurl.com/"+urllib.quote_plus("àieou"))
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Though it was `urllib.parse.quote` in Python 3.

Comment: Hmmm it still didn't work if the URL includes a space.

Comment: Its should work and replace space with +. There is some different .quote and .quote_plus. I dont know it currently at the moment, quote_plus is more hardcore.

Comment: May be you should use `quote_plus` instead of `quote`?

Comment: Yes @OlvinRoght , thought I used quote_plus

Comment: @Blaszard, I've posted my answer, you can select it, cause Wonka haven't edit this yet.

Comment: Seems that this does not work if the string includes both a capital letter and à`. Do you know the reason?

Comment: @Blaszard Upper and lower have different representation(À=%C3%80, à=%C3%A0) .In url doesnt matter upper and mayus, so its your jobs investigate how the website works, probably you have to use the lower codification representation

Answer (score 1):

Use [quote_plus()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus).

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

requests.get("http://myurl.com/" + quote_plus("àienah aie"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to url encode your value:

```
requests.get("http://myurl.com/%C3%A0ieou")
```

The value for `à` is `%C3%A0` once encoded.